# amazon debian AMI user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, debian, user-data

I've just try the Debian 7.1 AMI on AWS(from the Marketplace). I've some problem with my user-data script. 
He's not executed during the boot time, my script works well with the Amazon AMI but not with Debian(I've also try with a simple script: echo "toto" > /tmp/test.log but nothing).

Any idea?

Thanks

Matt

P.S: I start my script with #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the user-data script is executed only one time. If you create a AMI based on the Debian marketplace AMI, when you'll launch your "custom" AMI, the user-data has already been executed when you have started the Debian base AMI.

If you want that the user-data will be executed on a custom AMI, you must change the insserv for the init.d ec2-run-user-data:

sudo -i
insserv -d ec2-run-user-data

And now you can create an AMI.

Matt